# Get data from onDataChange

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to return a data from Firebase to a Java Object, but even using an Interface, it always returns me null. Some help?

I created a "Coordinate" object inside the method and I'm trying to access the data like this: `readData(value -> coordinates = value , offer);`

```
public interface CoordinatesCallback {
    void onCallBack(Coordinates value);
}

public void readData(CoordinatesCallback callback, Offer offer) {
    String storeId = Integer.toString(offer.getStore().getId());

    mDatabase.child("stores").child(storeId).child("coordinates").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Coordinates coordinates = dataSnapshot.getValue(Coordinates.class);

            callback.onCallBack(coordinates);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not how [getValue()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot.html#getValue(java.lang.Class%3CT%3E)) works.  You have to pass it the Class object of a Java POJO with getters and setters for each field of the database you want to read.  From the linked Javadoc:

> This method is used to marshall the data contained in this snapshot
>   into a class of your choosing. The class must fit 2 simple
>   constraints:
>
> 1. The class must have a default constructor that takes no arguments
> 2. The class must define public getters for the properties to be assigned. Properties without a public getter will be set to their
>      default value when an instance is deserialized

Comment: The getValue() method works fine. I got the object I wanted, I just can't use it outside of the onDataChange.